# Corollary 2.13 of Atiyah - Macdonald

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I just started learning about tensor products and I have some trouble understanding this corollary in Atiyah - Macdonald. All modules are assumed to be $A$ - modules for $A$ a commutative ring.

> > Corollary 2.13. Let $x_i \in M, y_i \in N$ such that $\sum x_i \otimes y_i = 0$ in $M \otimes N$. Then there exist finitely generated modules $M_0$ and $N_0$ of $M,N$ respectively such that $\sum x_i \otimes y_i = 0$ in $M_0 \otimes N_0$.

Now I know that if $\sum x_i \otimes y_i = 0$ in the tensor product of $M$ and $N$, then this means that $\sum (x_i,y_i)$ is in the submodule $D$ generated by elements of the form

$$\begin{eqnarray*} &(x_1 + x_2,y) - (x_1,y) - (x_2,y)&\\
&(x,y_1 + y_2) - (x,y_1) - (x,y_2)& \\
&(ax,y) - a(x,y)&\\
&(x,ay) - a(x,y)\\

\end{eqnarray*}$$

where $x_i \in N$, $y_i \in N$ and $a \in A$. It follows that $\sum (x_i,y_i)$ is a finite linear combination of elements of $D$. Now in the proof in AM, it says

> > "Let $M_0$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by the $x_i$ and all elements of $M$ which occur as first coordinates in these generators of $D$, and define $N_0$ similarly."

I don't understand what they mean in the definition of $M_0$ above. Don't all the $x_i$'s already appear as first coordinates in the generators of $D$? Besides why can't we just define $M_0$ to be generated by the $x_i$, $N_0$ generated by the $y_i$ ? Also I am not sure about how one defines $M_0 \otimes N_0$. Am I right to say that 
$$M_0 \otimes N_0 = F(M_0 \times N_0)/D$$

where $D$ is the submodule generated by the same relations above and $F(M_0 \times N_0)$ the free module on the set $M_0 \times N_0$?

Thanks.

Comment: the construction of $M_0$ and $N_0$ should make them big enough so that $M0 \times N0$ contain D and $\sum(x_i, y_i)$, so according to the definition of tensor product, sum(x_i tensor product y_i) = 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\sum(x_i,y_i)$ can be written as a finite linear combination of certain elements of $D$. Let $M_0$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by the first coordinates of the elements appearing *in that finite linear combination* and similarly for $N_0$.

**Remark.** One *has* to do this, for otherwise the result is not true. For example, let $R=\mathbb Z$, $M=\mathbb Z$ and $N=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, and let $x=2\in M$ and $y=1\in N$. Then $x\otimes y=0$ in $M\otimes N$, yet the element $x\otimes y$ is *not* zero in $M_0\otimes N_0$ with $M_0=(x)\subseteq M$ the submodule of $M$ generated by $x$ and $N_0=(y)\subseteq N$ the submodule of $N$ generated by $y$ (which happens to be equal to $N$, of course).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However how does $\sum x_i \otimes y_i = 0$ in $M_0 \otimes N_0$? Perhaps I don't know well what is $M_0 \otimes N_0$.

Comment: Indeed, you should read up a bit again on how to construct the tensor product, probably :)

Comment: The idea in the construction of $M_0 \otimes N_0$ is that you include enough that that same sum is an element of our tensor product, and also enough that it still dies (that's what the generators from D do).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Am I right in saying if we write $(2,1) = (7,1) - (2,1) - (3,1)$ and let $M_0 = (2,3,7)$, $N_0 = N$ then I can write $2 \otimes 1 = 2(1 \otimes 1)$ because $1 = \operatorname{gcd}(2,3,7)$. How can I show this works in general?

Comment: Do we need to include the $x_i$ (resp. $y_i$) from $\sum (x_i,y_i)$, or is it sufficient to ask for the elements which occur as first (resp. second) coordinates in the linear combination of generators of $D$? I tried to come up with some linear combinations, such that it wasn't possible to get an $x_i$ as a linear combination from the first coordinates, but so far I failed...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Is $D$ finitely-generated and if yes why? if not, why $\sum_i x_i\otimes y_i$ can be written as a **finite** sum of generators of $D$?